# Datamap not syncing between Android and Wear emulators

Tags: android

I have a problem with my wear watch face. I'm developing using Android Emulator and Wear Emulator. I can connect both emulators (I can change watch faces) but the communication between them is not working on app level - this is both Datamap API and Messaging API. There is basically no communication between them.
The application is working perfectly fine on two real devices.

Strange is that this was working 2 months ago, no I'm back and it does not work.

Any idea where the problem can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with the latest version of Google Play Services.
Version 9.6.1 does not work but the previous does:

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.4.0'
```

I had to load the googles example project which was using 9.4.0. Now it works.